# add new element in xml using python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

There is a list of strings such as `list=[ name, age, sex, roll, cgpa ]`

In python, how do I add these elements to XML?

I have written

```
from xml.dom import minidom
doc = minidom.Document()
testElem = doc.createElement("test")
testElem.setAttribute('id', '1234')
i=len(list)
while i:
    testElem.setAttribute('testing',list[i])
    i=i-1
doc.appendChild(testElem)
print doc.toxml()
```

When I run the above code it gives error in this line:

```
testElem.setAttribute('testing',list[i])
```

How do I solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the exact error message (use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11047895/edit) link to add the info).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the element at offset `len(list)`. This does not work since list indexes are zero-based. Start with `i=len(list)-1` instead and check for `i>=0` in your `while`